# postgresql select rows from same table twice

Tags: postgresql, join, left-join, outer-join, right-join

I want to compare `deposit` for each person in the table.
and return all the rows where the deposit field is decreased.

Here is what I have done so far;

The customer table is;

```
   person_id  employee_id  deposit  ts 
    101        201         44        2021-09-30 10:12:19+00
    100        200         45        2021-09-30 10:12:19+00
    101        201         47        2021-09-30 09:12:19+00
    100        200         21        2021-09-29 10:12:19+00
    104        203         54        2021-09-27 10:12:19+00
```

and as a result I want is;

```
   person_id  employee_id  deposit  ts 
    101        201         44        2021-09-30 10:12:19+00

SELECT person_id, 
       employee_id,
       deposit,
       ts,
       lag(deposit) over client_window as pre_deposit,
       lag(ts) over client_window as pre_ts
FROM customer 
WINDOW client_window as (partition by person_id order by ts)
ORDER BY person_id , ts
```

so it returns table with the following results;

```
   person_id  employee_id  deposit  ts                       pre_deposit   pre_ts
    101        201         44        2021-09-30 10:12:19+00    47          2021-09-30 09:12:19+00 
    100        200         45        2021-09-30 10:12:19+00    21          2021-09-29 10:12:19+00
    101        201         47        2021-09-30 09:12:19+00    null        null 
    100        200         21        2021-09-29 10:12:19+00    null        null
    104        203         54        2021-09-27 10:12:19+00    null        null


SELECT person_id, 
       employee_id,
       deposit,
       ts,
       lag(deposit) over client_window as pre_deposit,
       lag(ts) over client_window as pre_ts
FROM customer 
WINDOW client_window as (partition by person_id order by ts)
WHERE pre_deposit > deposit //this returns column not found for pre_deposit
ORDER BY person_id , ts
```

so far somehow I need to select the same table again to be able to apply this condition;

```
where pre_deposit > deposit
```

what does it make sense here?
union? outer-join? left-join? right-join?

Answer (score 0):

Use your query as a subquery and filter the results:

```
SELECT person_id, employee_id, deposit, ts
FROM (
  SELECT *, lag(deposit) over client_window as pre_deposit
  FROM customer 
  WINDOW client_window as (partition by person_id order by ts)
) t
WHERE deposit < pre_deposit 
ORDER BY person_id, ts;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c7c477c659e9e75df544e9baad3e5437).